# window.onbeforeunload doesn't triggered at once

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, onbeforeunload, jquery-dirtyforms

I use a jQuery Dirty Forms plugin in my web-application like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('form.checkUnsavedData').dirtyForms();           
});

$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){    
    if($.DirtyForms.isDirty()){             
        return($.DirtyForms.message);                               
    }           
});
```

But first click by any link doesn't trigger onbeforeunload event. Only the next clicks trigger it. This problem keeps in different browsers (google chrome, firefox, ie10). What's the matter?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you will need to add the [onBeforeUnload API](https://drupal.org/project/onbeforeunload) As it says in the [drupal Download & extend](https://drupal.org/project/dirtyforms) or else you should try not to bind the `beforeunload` through jQuery and do it with normal javascript like: `window.beforeunload = function(){/*code*/};`. Finally check what jQuery version are you using, what browsers and how they handle this event. Check out [Catching the Javascript beforeunload event, the cross-browser way](http://jonathonhill.net/2011-03-04/catching-the-javascript-beforeunload-event-the-cross-browser-way/) it's a little dated but it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

> What's the matter?

Dirty Forms automatically attaches to the `beforeunload` event. You are doing it *again*. This is likely causing your problematic behavior. You should change your code to just...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('form.checkUnsavedData').dirtyForms();           
});
```